# Append does not work when I try to code in Javascript OOP style

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am learning the concepts of programming in javascript OOP style and I need a little help:

First, a simple html form:

```
<form>
     <select id="jobRole"></select>
</form>
```

Next, I write the "Question" class:

```
var Question = function() {
  this.masterQ = function (id1) {
    this.id1 = jQuery(id1);
    this.id1.append('<option value="">test</option>');
  };
}
```

Now I instantiate the question class, making a new object

```
var q = new Question();
```

And now I call the masterQ method:

```
q.masterQ('#jobRole');
```

But, I have no idea why **test** isn't appended onto the select.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: I have no errors in the console

Comment: Are you running `q.masterQ('#jobRole');` inside a `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: When are you running the `var q = new Question(); ...` code?

Comment: Wow, i am soooo silly, no, I wasn't running it inside a doc ready....

Comment: Should I delete the question? Rocket Hazmat, maybe you should answer so I can approve it.

Comment: @DanyD: You can answer your own question and explain what was wrong.

Comment: Btw guys, what do you think about this style of javascript coding? Is it really useful? or should I stick with procedural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just try it and the code works -> http://jsfiddle.net/HxhH2/1/

Are you sure that you included jquery in your page

```
<script src="pathtojquery.js"></script>
```

Or you maybe execute the code before to get the dropdown on the page. It will be good to wrap your logic into

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // your code here
});
```